# supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); not working

Tags: android

hi i am trying to show progress bar on ActionBar since last four hours with no success. I have tried putting supportRequestWindowFeature above `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` still no success.
Here is code in OnCreate of my Activity extending ActionBarActivity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_find_loc, null);
    setContentView(mView);
    this.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
    this.setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    .......
}
```

//edit menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your xml file under menu folder?

Comment: @Soham, which xml file you are asking???

Comment: there should be progressbar in your layout if I am not wrong.That's layout I am talking about.

Comment: i don't have any progressbar in menu.xml it was never mentioned in any tutorial or resaurce i have searched. can you please give me a working example